# Toggle iCloud Sync iOS15 / SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, cloudkit

I have recently added iCloud into my iOS15 / SwiftUI App and wanted to implement an on/off toggle for it. I have already researched all forum posts and the best solution I came up with is:

```
struct PersistenceController {
...
init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "myAppName")
    
    if !iCloudSync {
        let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
        description?.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
        description?.setOption(true as NSNumber,
                               forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
...
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't work during runtime. The user has to close and re-open the app.

I already tried to add an onChange modifier including the code snippet to the root view but this doesn't do the trick.

Is there a way to toggle iCloud Sync during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will not work because you initialized `PersistenceController`.
What you can do is create a function in `PersistenceController` like so:

```
func toggleCloud() {
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "myAppName")
    if !iCloudSync {
        let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
        description?.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
        description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        ...
    }
}
```

And call it when the toggle changes.

Comment: Thank  you, very much appreciated! I agree with you that I have to create the function toggleCloud() and  I implemented this in my code. However, how do I access the current container after initialisation? I tried to add  `.onChange(of: iCloudSync) {_ in
                    persistenceController.toggleCloud()
                } ` where persistenceController is `var persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared`.

Comment: Yes you need to access the shared PersistenceController

Comment: This doesn't seem to work though. persistenceController is already the shared instance of PersistenceController. Weird. Thank you though!